# Multinomial logistic regression with random effects in R

Tags: r, regression, random-effects-model

I am trying to figure out how to run a multinomial logistic regression model with random effects in R. I am assuming I have to use mlogit.

my data:

```
data <- structure(list(Spawn_ID2 = 
c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 
 1, 2, 3), 

average_Ca = c(2382506.722, 2365097.923, 2435299, 2447003.947, 
2374565.588, 2347560.364, 2345150.667, 2442557.556, 3273328.407,
3270609.56, 3351219.8, 3114987.875, 3165870.444, 3358292.862, 
3195517.045, 3291476.448, 3138170.429, 3359619.591, 3016741.214, 
1106471.379, 1146784,1118023.857, 1137698.28, 1148620.348, 
1109930.897, 1142559.105, 1156635.889, 1760035.014, 1773782.642, 
1875688.488, 1787187.905, 1805407.841, 1691737.88, 1807261.653, 
1657850.143, 1828079.822, 1794295.639, 1798622.771, 1525681.789, 
1614503.238, 1745480.895, 1521216.958, 1634043.276, 1516681.815, 
1586493.148, 1684308.214,1434130.895, 1699360.714, 1429283.944, 
1445841.263), 

average_Mn = c(60.00633222, 48.80424538, 51.06187909, 57.30724947, 
50.31859294, 53.87041955, 48.09621286, 52.51352389, 36.08437333, 
39.8565816, 87.17658667, 99.6882075, 29.64281944, 76.06302414, 
89.95301455, 29.3972869, 
33.46448786, 80.81569273, 84.66107357, 20.19708207, 23.12141063, 
17.41069214, 20.387258, 22.29570696, 18.87749483, 25.98137842, 
23.60160889, 43.43359357, 34.87588094, 52.71391744, 54.75980762, 
39.66991175, 34.6280406, 42.9865002, 37.78165262, 42.19553699, 
50.66384667, 42.765985, 34.34720632, 20.30738429, 37.93858579,                                                                                                                                                                                
26.44302083, 30.02583379, 25.09235037, 15.02555489, 26.15761357,                                                                                                                                                                                
33.32728053, 25.01752, 44.72356, 25.83267263), 

average_Zn = c(215.4566278, 245.3482731, 305.0549818, 225.5911947, 
242.9557176, 209.0609273,214.8873857, 306.4080778, 170.2043667, 
194.158624, 289.9295867, 246.5235125, 165.7625722, 259.0388207, 
237.9360227, 152.5834483, 170.3427929, 289.1114, 230.3927929, 
97.88223655, 143.6127, 81.73639143, 107.9251376, 146.4331, 95.72906069, 
130.2766895, 125.9697217, 122.5505496, 114.468913, 106.7186195, 
88.85797238, 127.6454889, 
107.9937798, 99.42765429, 111.497753, 117.3362116, 110.2091247,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
93.50748042, 153.0925632, 130.3422952, 231.5591474, 140.4616558,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
169.0629138, 125.8872507, 103.3344659, 185.0892643, 167.5173421,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
198.9136643, 187.9697611, 169.3105316), 

ID = c("BLA14", "BLA14", "BLA14", "BLA14", "BLA14", "BLA14", "BLA14", 
"BLA14", "BLA2", "BLA2", "BLA2", "BLA2", "BLA2", "BLA2", "BLA2", "BLA2", 
"BLA2", "BLA2", "BLA2", "BLA20", "BLA20", "BLA20", "BLA20", "BLA20", 
"BLA20", "BLA20", "BLA20", "BLA209", "BLA209", "BLA209", "BLA209",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
"BLA209", "BLA209", "BLA209", "BLA209", "BLA209", "BLA209", "BLA209",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
"BLA21", "BLA21", "BLA21", "BLA21", "BLA21", "BLA21", "BLA21",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
"BLA21", "BLA211", "BLA211", "BLA211", "BLA211")), row.names = c(NA,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Spawn_ID2 is the response variable (3 levels). `average_Ca`, `Average_Mn`, and `average_Zn` are the predictor variables and then `ID` would be the random effect (This is a very small subset of the data).

My current code:

```
rpl <- mlogit(Spawn_ID2 ~ average_Ca + Average_Mn + average_Zn, 
              data = data, rpar = c(ID= 'n'))
```

Comment: A multinomial regression is just a bunch of logistic regressions. With that line of reasoning, why can't you fit a bunch of mixed logit models with the random intercept structure of interest?